# printing variables in python using % and variable name

Tags: python

I am currently learning python and would like to know how these two print statements are different? I mean both perform the same action but only differ in the syntax. Are there any other differences?

```
a = 5
b = 'hi'

print "The number is", a, " and the text is", b

print "The number is %d and the text is %s" %(a, b)
```

Comment: First one won't even run.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary It's just missing a comma.

Comment: Consider ``print("The number is {} and the text is {}".format(a, b))``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the second one will fail if the variable `a` is not a number.

```
>>> a='hi'
>>> b='hi'
>>> print "The number is %d and the text is %s" %(a, b)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-aa94a92667a1> in <module>()
----> 1 print "The number is %d and the text is %s" %(a, b)

TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

If `a` is always a number, they would behave very much alike, except the `%d` in the format forces it to be an integer, so if you have:

```
>>> a=1.2
>>> b='hi'
>>> print "The number is %d and the text is %s" %(a, b)
The number is 1 and the text is hi
```

You can see that it converts the number `1.2` to an integer `1`.

As per the comments, another option is to use the [format function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format), that behaves similar to your first option but using a [format string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
>>> a=1.2
>>> b='hi'
>>> print "The number is {} and the text is {}".format(a, b)
The number is 1.2 and the text is hi
```

It also allows to use named arguments:

```
>>> print "The number is {number} and the text is {text}".format(number=a, text=b)
The number is 1.2 and the text is hi
```

Comment: I'm deleting my answer because yours in much better, but for the sake of completeness you should consider providing a description of the ```format()``` function

Comment: @wnnmaw Okay, I'll add a note. If you want, you can suggest an edit too, and I'll apply. =)

Comment: Just a warning, "the first one" has changed since you answered (the question was edited). Now in the first one `a` can't be a number (`repr()` is no longer called), and in the second one it must be!

Comment: @SteveJessop ops, someone other than the OP changed the question inadvertently -- let me change it back.

Comment: yes initially I had posted `print "The number is", a, "and the text is", b` Not sure why it was edited by moderators because even this statement prints a and b

Comment: @user732362 I think people edited it because it was missing the first comma.

Comment: I'll throw my name in the hat for suggesting use of the `str.format` function instead of string concatenation or interpolation using `%s`. `str.format` is very robust, and makes debugging a breeze when you know "Hey, something's going wrong here, let's just do `"a is {a} and b is {b} and c is {c} and foo is {foo} and bar is {bar}".format(**locals())` (though NEVER use `locals()` in production code)

Comment: @adsmith that's a nice trick to use with `python -i` -- thanks for that! I think  you need to use `**locals()` in the call to `format()`, though.